# How to render a template page by calling its method from TAL portlet(@@manage-portlets)

Tags: plone, portlet, zope

How do I call a method which is in the filesystem from a TAL Portlet (made available by `collective.portlet.tal`)?

This is how I did it: I defined a new BrowserView (`createPictMenu.py` in my case) and then registered it as the renderer for a new portlet component:

```
class AddressTAL(BrowserView)

    def my_address()
        address_bar = ViewTemplatePageFile('templates/address_left.pt') # this 
         is the page template I want for my new portlet.
```

And in `configure.zcml`:

```
<plone:portlet
    name="collective.portlet.tal.TALPortlet"
    interface="collective.portlet.tal.talportlet.ITALPortlet"
    assignment="collective.portlet.tal.talportlet.Assignment"
    view_permission="zope2.View"
    edit_permission="cmf.ManagePortal"
    renderer=".browser.createPictMenu.AddressTAL"
    addview="collective.portlet.tal.talportlet.AddForm"
    editview="collective.portlet.tal.talportlet.EditForm"
    />
```

Then I went to localhost:8080/myproject/@@manage-portlets and selected the `TAL Portlet option` from the Add Portlet dropdown list. I informed title as address and for description I inserted the snippet below to call `address_tal()`:

```
<span tal:define="global li view/myaddress">
    <span tal:replace="structure li" /> 
</span>
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: If you only change the renderer you should use plone:portletRenderer. Please allow me to ask, what is the final goal of your customization? Because I think collective.portlet.tal is not what you need.

Comment: I created my TAL Portlet.I want to get return value of method of one class which is in filesystem(createPictMenu.py) in TAL Portlet. How to access the method in TAL Portlet(in zmi)....

Comment: @@mat: I Will send you one link which i explained about my need clearly(i think). So please have a look at http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/How-to-render-a-template-page-by-calling-its-method-from-TAL-portlet-manage-portlets-tt7567464.html#a7567490

Comment: So you have a template that renders a template that calls a method that renders a template. What possesses you to think this is a good idea?

Comment: Voting to close as you don't explain what the problem is. python: `view.myaddress()` is a correct way to call a portlet renderer view method.

Comment: Please provide an error description in your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have registered your class AddressTAL with a browser:view directive, not a plone:portlet one. Like this:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser">

  <browser:page
      name="address-view"
      class=".browser.createPictMenu.AddressTAL"
      for="*"
      permission="zope2.View"
      />

</configure>
```

And then call it with:

```
<div tal:define="my_address python:context.restrictedTraverse('@@address-view').my_address()" >
    Your method returns <span tal:content="my_address" />
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div tal:define="address_view context/@@address-view" >
    Your method returns <span tal:content="address_view/my_address" />
</div>
```

Comment: The AddressTAL view is actually the portlet renderer. Hence `view/my_address` should be enough. My guess is that the problem is that they forgot the `self`. But since they don't provide an error message...

Comment: @@Davi Lima: Hi davi,thanks for your msg now i m getting my output some what. But i have to correct it to get exact output which i expected. Thanks for the help

Comment: @@Davi : Hi, TAL portlet is working fine but now the problem is m just getting the entire addressleft.pt html code. But i want it to be display only the content not the entire code. So what i have to change further.

Answer (score 0):

It's of very little information or matter that the method is on the file system. That's where it should be. Having it in the ZODB is possible but a bad idea.

But there are many types of methods, and how you call them from TAL differs.

You can have what in the ZMI is called "Script (Python) methods" that are accessed through portal_skins, you can have methods on content objects and you can have methods on views. These are all callable from TAL.

For methods that are neither of these, you will have to create a method of the above type that you can call, which in turn then calls the method you want to call. For a portlet the obvious place to create that method is by adding a method on the Renderer, which is a type of view, and which you can call from the portlets template.

In your case, the method you want to call *is* a method on the renderer already. That means you just call it.

```
<p tal:content="view/myaddress" />
```

Note that you have forgotten the `self` parameter in the definition. Also, please follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @@regebro:I dont want to put a taladdress() method in zmi script. Why means. The class and the method is not truly independent. Some of its values is fetched by another class which is in creatPictMenu.py. So its not good idea for me to put the method alone in zmi script

Comment: @@regebro: So only thing i can do is i have to call the method from file system to get return values in TAL Portlet

Comment: @nirmala: Your comments are like random generated text and make no sense whatsoever. "I dont want to put a taladdress() method in zmi script. " - I didn't tell you to do that. In fact I told you to NOT do that. Read my answer. Explain which words you don't understand.

Comment: @@regebro: You said this "You can have what in the ZMI is called "Script (Python) methods" that are accessed through portal_skins, you can have methods on content objects and you can have methods on views. These are all callable from TAL." thays y i told you that i dont want to put the method directly inside the zmi script

Comment: @@regebro: I cant understand part which you told me "For methods that are neither of these, you will have to create a method of the above type that you can call, which in turn then calls the method you want to call. For a portlet the obvious place to create that method is by adding a method on the Renderer, which is a type of view, and which you can call from the portlets template."

Comment: @nirmala: Do you understand the difference between "can" and "should"? Yes, you *can* have that. I didn't say you *should*.

Comment: @nirmala: Ignore that bit. I tried making a generally useful answer, this is what you do on Stackoverflow. What *you* should do is delete the portlet and start over. You don't want to use the TAL portlet.

Comment: @@regebro: I understood that you didnt me that "i should do like that".But i just tried to explain that i want that way to do

Comment: @nirmala: You want to do it that way? Above you said you did NOT want to do it that way. In any case, you should not do it that way.

Comment: @nirmala OK, good. Now delete whatever you are doing, and create a new portlet, based on how to make portlets in Aspelis book, as I know you have it. Just copy that code. You can also use [ZopeSkel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZopeSkel) to create a basic portlet with less typing.

Comment: @@regebro: Will do it. Thanks for your advice

Comment: can anyone tell us what is the TAL code for calling a method which is in filesystem from TAL Portlet(in zmi)

Comment: @nirmala `<p tal:content="view/myaddress" />` Note that you have forgotten the self parameter in the definition. Also, please learn to read.

Comment: @@regebro: I used the line <p tal:content="view/myaddress" /> in TAL portlet.. but its not working. I m reading the documents and trying it

Comment: @nirmala: I'm starting to think that you have a learning disability or something. How many times have I told you that "It's not working" isn't a useful error description? I don't think I've ever talked with a programmer that is so stubbornly and brutally incompetent as you. Why is it so impossible for you to include an error description or a traceback?

Comment: @@regebro: I include self in my code. But its my mistake i didn't post it correctly. So the problem is not with self in method

Comment: @nirmala: You didn't understand a word I just said, did you?